# How can I find my saved draft answers?

Tags: support, answers, draft

I had a question I thought deserved a well written answer, but I realized part way through writing it, I didn't have the correct answer. I did some more research and I am ready to finish answering the question (I hope), and I cannot find the question. I browse Stack Overflow quite frequently and haven't been able to locate the question with my browser history, or searching through the tagged questions.

How can I find a saved draft of an answer?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting

Comment: But generally, I do not think you do the reverse search that you want to do: find the question for which you have a saved draft. I you open the question, you'll see the draft in the answer box.

Comment: Side note: while it is mostly abuse of features, posting half-complete answer and immediately deleting it may be better approach in such case as "recently deleted" is readily accessible from the profile unlike drafts... Note that such answer will be visible to 10k+ users and moderators - adding "this post is temporary deleted till I find answer to xxxx part" will clarify your intentions and could help you remember what you wanted to do.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov or just bookmark or star the question

Comment: Look in your browser's history for the question page.

Comment: Side note: alternatively, just leave the tab opened until you're ready to post the answer (like me, having a few tabs for more than 1 week with partial answer drafts)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unless you find the question, you're out of luck. The details of the draft mechanism are specified in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111578/295232):

> Drafts are stored in redis for 7 days.
>
> For anonymous we use cookie to track the user.
>   For non anonymous we use the user id.
>
> We ship it to the server in the heartbeat (once a minute or so), the
>   heartbeat also notifies you when new answers were added in the banner
>   on the top.
>
> We only store drafts for new answers and new questions, not for edits.

There is no page on the Stack Overflow site with a list of your drafts, and since the drafts are stored server-side, you cannot browse your local storage / cookies for question IDs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Hopefully this list is on a list somewhere for the future.

Comment: Are you sure that drafts aren't stored on the client side as well? Especially since the cited answer is from 2011…

Comment: @Bergi switching browsers, or clearing your local storage, does not remove the drafts. I *did* check my local storage but found nothing that appears to store draft information.